# How do I add max_id to my twitter (tweepy) request? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to pull all tweets older than a certain max_id. However, I can't figure out where to add the max_id in my request in order to pull tweets older than that the specified tweet. I want to do this without changing the count. Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
import time
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import datetime
import tweepy

ct = "INSERT CONSUMER TOKEN"
cs = "INSERT CONSUMER SECRET"
at = "INSERT ACCESS TOKEN"
acs = "INSERT CONSUMER SECRET"
count = 1

twitter = "transportgovuk"
consumer_token = ct
consumer_secret = cs
access_token = at
access_secret = acs
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

api  = tweepy.API(auth)

max_id = "724916468975046656"

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,twitter).items(count):
    print status
```

Is there a way of pulling the tweet directly after the specified max_id without changing the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just have to add max_id to the tweepy.Cursor for loop like this:

```
import requests
import time
import json
import urllib
import urllib2
import datetime
import tweepy

ct = "INSERT CONSUMER TOKEN"
cs = "INSERT CONSUMER SECRET"
at = "INSERT ACCESS TOKEN"
acs = "INSERT CONSUMER SECRET"
count = 1

twitter = "transportgovuk"
consumer_token = ct
consumer_secret = cs
access_token = at
access_secret = acs
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

api  = tweepy.API(auth)

status_ids= "724916468975046656"

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,twitter,max_id=status_ids).items(count):
    print status
```

That should pull the tweet with the status_id "724916468975046656." If you want more, change your count to a number higher than 1.